# Wifi not working with Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwlwifi

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X220. I recently changed my hard disk drive to an SSD and installed Arch Linux on it.

What happens is that, when I try to connect to a Wifi Network via `wifi-menu`, it doesn't connect. `wifi-menu` shows me the different networks that are available to connect, and when typing the password it immediately fails.

Not sure what drivers I should install, and the only way I can connect to the Internet is through a wired connection.

I think this can be useful:

```
> $ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit 
Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520 [17aa:21ce]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino 
Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n) 
[8086:1311]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

So this is the output for when trying to connect manually using `wpa_supplicant`

```
> $ sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp3s0  
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:51 (SSID='CATEGORIES' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:51 (SSID='CATEGORIES' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp3s0: Associated with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:51
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=82:2a:a8:31:9c:51 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:36 (SSID='CATEGORIES' freq=2412 MHz)
wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:51 (SSID='CATEGORIES' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:51 (SSID='CATEGORIES' freq=2437 MHz)
wlp3s0: Associated with 82:2a:a8:31:9c:51
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp3s0: WPA: Failed to set PTK to the driver (alg=3 keylen=16 bssid=82:2a:a8:31:9c:51)
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=82:2a:a8:31:9c:51 reason=1 locally_generated=1
wlp3s0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="CATEGORIES" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
^Cnl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Comment: Connect manually: it will provide more detailed debugging information.

Comment: How did you create the conf file? What commands did you use? Can you post the conf (with the passphrase redacted)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the state of your wifi interface with `ip link`. If it is down, you can bring it up with `sudo ip link set dev [your interface name] up`.

As jasonwryan stated, connecting manually (you can use `wpa_supplicant`) might give you more information on the problem.

Comment: When using `wpa_supplicant` I'm seeing authentication problems but I'm totally sure I'm using the right key for the right ESSID.

Comment: Did you form a config file with `wpa_passphrase`?

Comment: Yes, and the information put there is correct.

Comment: @sant016 "authentication problems" is not a helpful description, nor an error message. Edit your question with full output.

Comment: @jasonwryan now edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In the begining I have the same Problem with WiFi-Menu, then I mannualy connect with the internet like this:

1. Discover what is your interface with the follow command: `iwconfig`

   Normally, your wifi interface is like this construct: `wlp2s0`. I'll put `<interface name>` where you need to put your interface
2. Put the interface up:

   ```
   ip link set <interface name> up
   ```
3. Scan your interface to see if it is enabled:

   ```
   iwlist <interface name> scan | less
   ```
4. If it is in the list, down the interface:

   ```
   ip link set interface down
   ```
5. Go the `netctl` examples Directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/netctl/examples
   ```
6. Copy the `wireless-wpa` to `netctl` Directory with the name you want:

   ```
   cp /etc/netctl/examples/wireless-wpa /etc/netctl/wifi_name
   ```
7. Open the `wireless-wpa` file to edit with your preferred editor (e.g. `nano`):

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/netctl/wifi_name
   ```
8. Change the following settings:

   ```
   Interface: <Interface name>
   ESSID: <your internet name>
   key: <your internet password>
   ```

   Save and exit
9. Run the `netctl` with the following commands:

   ```
   cd /etc/netctl
   netctl start wifi_name
   ```
10. If an error message appears, try this commad:

    ```
    ip link set dev <interface name> down
    ```
11. try run your internet connectivity:

    ```
    ping -c 3 www.google.com
    ```
12. If working, enable your internet to run permanently:

    ```
    netctl enable wifi_name
    ```

Answer (score -2):

Try installing the `NetworkManager` package using `chroot` in the install media and use `nmtui`.